# Using a subdomain for email address

Tags: email, spam-filter

I have recently acquired a domain which closely resembles my last name (basically there are two words in my name and the domain is only the second word). The plan was to use a subdomain in order to have email@complete.name.com instead of email@name.com, as completename.com was already taken. I know the sending part is possible, as the sending email is just a header in the email, but I have two remaining issues:

1. Will my sent emails get caught in spam filters, if yes, how do I resolve this issue?
2. Will emails sent to this email address get to me if I have email@name.com set up?

Comment: Will you be configuring SPF for your domain?

Comment: No, I don't really know what that is precisely

Answer (score 3):

The spam filters questions is a very large one and really depends on the content of the messages.  What I think you are really asking it whether the connection from your mail server will be accepted by the remote SMTP server, usually referred to as an MTA.  MTA are frequently configured to reject connections from MTA's whose reverse DNS lookup does not match the forward lookup.  If you are sending mail from some place like Gmail this is not a problem.  If you are running your own MTA you have to make sure the reverse DNS entry points to the name of your server.

You will want to at least create a DNS MX record for complete.name.com that points to your MTA and your MTA will need to be configured to recognize that mail for complete.name.com should be delivered to name.com.

Answer (score 1):

> Will my sent emails get caught in spam filters, if yes, how do I resolve this issue?

I see no reason to suspect that using a subdomain would make your emails more likely to be treated as spam. Subdomains are used pretty frequently for email addresses in larger organizations.

> Will emails sent to this email address get to me if I have email@name.com set up?

No. You will need to specifically set up mail service for the subdomain, exactly as you would set up mail for any other domain: the subdomain must have MX records, and the mail server(s) listed in those MX records must be configured to accept mail for the subdomain.

Comment: Could you please give me more details on how to do this? I really don't know anything about this stuff. Sorry to bother...